# Bash script to check for new e-mails doesn't recognize new messages

Tags: bash, email, gmail, imap

I wrote a little bash script I want to start automatically when I log in to my desktop.
The script shall always run in background and periodically check for new incoming mail messages. When a new message arrives, the script shall pop up a notification via notify-send, and display its content.

However, if I send myself an email (from another address) to check if it's working, it seems that the message has already been consumed, even if in the Gmail's web interface (that I keep closed) the message is marked as unread. Obviously, since even the new message is not marked as new, the script doesn't fetch it.

I also switched off my android phone, because I think that it could interfere, and I'm sure I have no other mail clients running.

The output of the script is the following; note that between these two lines I send myself a message:

```
254 messages, 0 new
255 messages, 0 new
```

The code follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER="imap.gmail.com"
while :
do
    echo "1 login myusername mypassword" > /tmp/checkmail
    echo "2 select inbox" >> /tmp/checkmail
    echo "3 logout" >> /tmp/checkmail

    response=$(openssl s_client -crlf -connect $SERVER:993 -quiet 2> /dev/null < /tmp/checkmail)
    rm /tmp/checkmail

    news=$(echo "$response" | grep RECENT | awk '{print $2}')
    last=$(echo "$response" | grep EXISTS | awk '{print $2}')

    echo "$last messages, $news new"

    if [ "$news" != "0" ]
    then
        for (( i=0; i<$news; i++))
        do
            echo "fetching $i° message"
            echo "1 login myusername mypassword" > /tmp/getmail
            echo "2 select inbox" >> /tmp/getmail
            echo "3 fetch $((last-i)) (body[1])" >> /tmp/getmail
            echo "4 logout" >> /tmp/getmail
            response=$(openssl s_client -crlf -connect $SERVER:993 -quiet 2> /dev/null < /tmp/getmail)
            rm /tmp/getmail

            content=$(echo "$response" | awk '/FETCH/{flag=1;next}/3 OK Success/{flag=0}flag')
            notify-send -t 0 "New message" "$content"
        done
    fi
    sleep 60 
done
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: [This page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78761) seems like it might be relevant.

Comment: Would you mind showing the output of the command `openssl s_client`?

Comment: 'RECENT' is almost entirely unusable with multiple clients.  Use UIDs and get newer UIDs than what you have, or search for unseen messages, or something.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the very same problem, with the gmail imap server. I have therefore resorted to modify your script adding one extra IMAP command:

```sh
    echo "1 login $myusername $mypassword" > /tmp/checkmail
    echo "2 select inbox" >> /tmp/checkmail
    echo "3 STATUS inbox (UNSEEN)" >> /tmp/checkmail
    echo "4 logout" >> /tmp/checkmail
```

and then replacing your definition of $news with the one below

```sh
    news=$(echo "$response" | grep UNSEEN | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/)//' | tr -d '\r')
```

Note that the removal of '\r' was required for the forthcoming script to work.

I am nonetheless still struggling to make the next steps of your original script working on my setup.